# ActionLink does not show id parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My code is very simple and listed below:

I just want to pass id to the controller when I click on actionlink.

```
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>@item.Name</td>

                <td>@item.Cause</td>

                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit","EditA","N",null,new {id=item.ActId})</td>
            </tr>
        }
```

With the above code currently the URL is generated like "N/EditA".

But I want the URL in this format "N/EditA/id". Any suggestions?

Comment: We need to see the controller.

Comment: I have reformatted the title and body of the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Try removing null argument from parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using the overload incorrectly and adding the `id` as a html attribute, not as a route value. It needs to be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditA", "N", new { id = item.ActId }, null)
```

[Refer documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","EditA","N",new {id=item.ActId})
```